# Include a PHP file inside an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a custom PHP script inside of the nav menu (before the closing ) and struggling.

Code here:

```
<?php
      wp_nav_menu(array(
                        'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                        'menu_id' => 'primary-menu',
                        'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s<div class="my-div">' . $addCats . '</div></ul>'
                    ));
      $addCats = require_once('custom_menu_addon.php');
?>
```

The above code includes the file outside of the new  added to the menu:

[image]

Any recommendations for getting this to print inside the div?
Am I using the wrong command to pull the file contents there?

Thank you in advance for your help and guidance! <3

Comment: You can't have a `<div>` as a direct child of an `<ul>`, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: I'm aware, it's going to be further list items but at the moment im just testing what I can print. I was concerned I may have been printing closing tags and whats why it was breaking and therefore tried <div>s!..

Comment: What’s even in the PHP file? HTML?

Comment: PHP, its a cool script we made to fetch categories etc. using it as a dropdown for the final item of the menu. Edited the answer below, seems to work well. Thanks guys! <3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please Use Below code

```
<?php
$addcats = array();
ob_start();
require 'custom_menu_addon.php';
$addCats = ob_get_clean();
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
    'menu_id' => 'primary-menu',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s<div class="my-div">' . $addCats . '</div></ul>'
));
```

I've edited this answer after some research into the usage of this object array and put it in context with my code, works well on the site :)

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: As above, I've edited to relate to the question. Good answer but more context would definitely help, I asked because i do not know PHP so well yet - putting it in context was a struggle but @Er was on the right path indeed :)